# "Cannot read file" error when loading an .svg file with PyQt4

Tags: python, svg, pyqt, pyqt4, qicon

I'm having troubles using a .svg icon for my windows icon. From what I have read this is due to a bad installation of the PyQt4 plugins, but I am confused on how to fix it.
When I try to load the image

```
self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("File-View-front.svg"))
```

Here is the error message I get:

```
Cannot read file 'C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/proj1/File-
View-front.svg', because:  (line 2)
```

I tried printing the supported image formats with

```
for imageType in QtGui.QImageReader.supportedImageFormats():
    print(imageType)
```

Which outputs:

```
b'bmp'
b'pbm'
b'pgm'
b'png'
b'ppm'
b'xbm'
b'xpm'
```

So I am missing formats... If I add the correct plugin path with

```
QtCore.QCoreApplication.addLibraryPath('C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/PyQt4/plugins')
```

(which if I understand correctly I could also do using `conf.py`, but I could not get that to work either)

I do get every format (including `b'svg'`) using `QtGui.QImageReader.supportedImageFormats()`, but the error remains. 
I am using Anaconda 4.3.1 and I installed PyQt4 with the wheel file I got [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

Comment: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/131 I think its know bug

Comment: I think you're right. I switched to PyQt5 and I don't have any problem now.